How to move a 3d object to the top left corner of the screen in Unity?
I need to align the top left of a gameObject with the top left corner of my camera view. How to move a 3d object to the top left corner of the screen in Unity? I can't seen to figure this out and the posts I found are in Unity 2D.
Thank you for your help.

Unity fakes 2d, so chances are you do trhe same thing you found in 2d.  Get the top left corner of the screen bounds, do a raycast to the world, it will give you the point - adjust according to size of item being spawned

The following script moves a given GameObject to the top left corner of the screen at its current distance to the camera. Change if desired. It refines the object's position based on its renderer extents relative to the camera:
public class SpawnScreenCorner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip("Main cam")]
    private Camera mainCam;

    [Tooltip("Gameobject to be aligned")]
    public GameObject objToBeAligned;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Cache main camera
        mainCam = Camera.main;

        // Align obj to top left corner
        AlignObj();
    }

    // Align object to top left corner of screen
    public void AlignObj()
    {
        // Parent obj to camera temporarily
        Transform prevParent = objToBeAligned.transform.parent;
        objToBeAligned.transform.SetParent(mainCam.transform, false);

        // Get the screen's top-left corner in screen coordinates at current distance (z) of object 
        Vector3 screenTopLeft = new Vector3(0, Screen.height, objToBeAligned.transform.localPosition.z);

        // Convert the screen top-left corner to a world position
        Vector3 worldTopLeft = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenTopLeft);

        // Adjust for the GameObject's size to align the top-left corner relative to camera space
        Vector3 adjustedPosition = worldTopLeft + mainCam.transform.InverseTransformVector(new Vector3(objToBeAligned.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.extents.x, -objToBeAligned.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.extents.y, objToBeAligned.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.extents.z));

        // Unparent object again
        objToBeAligned.transform.SetParent(prevParent);

        // Set the GameObject's position
        objToBeAligned.transform.position = adjustedPosition;
    }
}

